# Run-Time Error 462 - Delete Outlook Appointments from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The code below deletes appointments in a subfolder of the Outlook default calendar. I have commented out the line giving the run-time error 462: "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable".

Is there a change I could make to this code to solve this error? Thanks for any guidance.

```
Public Sub DeleteAppt()

Dim olApp As Object 'Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Object 'Outlook.Namespace
Dim olAptItemFolder As Object 'Outlook.Folder
Dim olAptItem As Object 'Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim i As Long

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNS = olApp.Session
Set olAptItemFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("TestCal")

''''For i = olAptItemFolder.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set olAptItem = olAptItemFolder.Items(i)
    If olAptItem.Subject Like "***" Then
        olAptItem.Delete
    End If
Next i

Set olAptItem = Nothing
Set olAptItemFolder = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure you marked the right line?

Comment: Your issue likely originates from `Set olAptItemFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("TestCal")` . `olFolderCalendar` is part of the Outlook object model, not Excel.  In the absence of `option Explicit` Excel will create a variable and initialise it to `0` .  Either qualify it back to `olApp` or use [its value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861868(v=office.15).aspx) `9`

Comment: Did you define `olFolderCalendar` somewhere? It's a built in Outlook constant which equals `9`.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I think I understand what you're recommending but am not experienced enough to know how to write this. Could you direct me to or provide an example?

Comment: @elpizzic `Set olAptItemFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(9).Folders("TestCal")`

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I'm still getting the same run-time error after changing that line. Any suggestions?

Comment: Should be 'Set olAptItemFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("TestCal").Items'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`olAptItemFolder` has no `Count` property. `olAptItemFolder.Items` does. Apart from the issues others noted in comments above, try

```
For i = olAptItemFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
```

Edited to add: if you are not setting a reference to something's object lirary, you can't use its enums unless you fully qualify each use. It's generally simpler, easier and quicker to find out the numerical value of the enum and use that instead. Then add a comment on the end of the line to remind yoursef, six months from now, that `'9 = olFolderCalendar`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I am away from the file currently and will update as soon as I can.

Comment: After making the suggested change I then get "run-time error '-2147221233 (8004010f)': The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found"  on the previous line `Set olAptItemFolder = ...`
Not sure what I should do here to resolve this. I appreciate your help resolving the previous error.

Comment: Are you using `Set olAptItemFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(9).Folders("TestCal")` or are you using your old `Set olAptItemFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("TestCal")`?

Comment: I've got `Set olAptItemFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(9).Folders("TestCal")`